# Pandoc LuaLatex error: cannot find image file

Tags: luatex, pandoc, markdown

I've recently started having a weird error when converting a file from markdown to PDF using Pandoc with LuaLatex as the PDF engine when including PDF images.

Running `pandoc -i 1384e7d0c2.md -o test.pdf --pdf-engine=lualatex` on a Markdown file yields the following error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! error:  (file "/tmp/tex2pdf.-f23128305f8b8fe3/""c683e86dfecf4c7ba8f65730919b05
50d0deef84".pdf) (pdf backend): cannot find image file '"/tmp/tex2pdf.-f23128305
f8b8fe3/""c683e86dfecf4c7ba8f65730919b0550d0deef84".pdf'
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

All of the PDF images are included in this format: `![name](diagrams/19-07-10_23-23-44.pdf)`.

It seems like LuaLatex is adding " and ' characters to the paths that shouldn't be there, but I am not sure about what to do to remedy this.

Comment: you will have an old version of grffile (the package is not needed any more but the new version of grffile does nothing, so as to avoid the error you show) update your tex system and the error should go

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'll update this question as soon as I have my laptop at hand.